# Solving the differential equation: $dy/(dx) = xy(x ^ 2 y ^ 2 - 1) $

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm given with the differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = xy(x ^ 2 y ^ 2 - 1). $$

I tried putting $xy=p$ but it would result in a cubic of $p$. How to do it?

Comment: **Hint** Start with $y=\frac 1 {\sqrt z}$

Comment: This diff equation is equivalent to $$y'+xy=x^3y^3.$$
This is a Bernoulli differential equation. It can be solved by substituting $u=y^{-2}.$

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%28x%29%2Bxy%3Dx%5E3+y%5E3&lang=es

Answer (score 1):

$y'=x^3y^3-xy \implies y'+xy=x^3y^3 \implies y^{-3}y'+xy^{-2}=x^3$
This id Bernoulli eqn, Let y $y^{-2}=v\implies -2y^{-3}y]=v'$. So we have a linear ODE as

$-\frac{v'}{2}+xv=x^3 \implies v'-2xv=-2x^3$. The integrating factor is $I=e^{-x^2}$, so the solution is
$v=e^{x^2}\int x^3 e^{-x^2} dx+Ce^{x^2} \implies v= (1+x^2)+C e^{x^2}=y^{-2}$