# Solving differential equation: $\frac{d y}{d x}\left(x^{2} y^{3}+x y\right)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I went this way

$\frac{d y}{d x}\left(x^{2} y^{3}+x y\right)=1$

let $x y=p$

$\frac{d y}{d x}=-\frac{1}{x^{2}} p+\frac{1}{x} \frac{d p}{d x}$

$\left(-\frac{1}{x^{2}} p+\frac{1}{x} \frac{d p}{d x}\right)\left(\frac{p^{3}}{x}+p\right)=1$

$\left(\frac{d p}{d x}\left(\frac{p^{3}}{x^{2}}+\frac{p}{x}\right)-\frac{p}{x^{2}}\left(\frac{p^{3}}{x}+p\right)=1\right.$

$\frac{d p}{d x}\left(p^{3}+x p\right)-\left(\frac{p^{4}+xp^{2}}{x}\right)=x^{2}$

Now let

$p^{4}+x p^{2}=m x$

$4 p^{3} \frac{d p}{d x}+2 p x \frac{d p}{d x}+p^{2}=m+x \frac{d m}{d x}$

Now what next?

Is this approach correct?

Comment: Exchange $x$ and $y$ in   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488621/solving-the-differential-equation-dy-dx-xyx-2-y-2-1/4488675#4488675

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{d y}{d x}\left(x^{2} y^{3}+x y\right)=1$$
**Hint:**
$$\left(x^{2} y^{3}+x y\right)=\dfrac {dx}{dy}$$
This is Bernouilli's DE.
$$x'=x^{2} y^{3}+x y$$